# EF6 Model First and the TPH Inheritance Mapping Strategy

Tags: entity-framework, tph

I'm using VS 2013 Premium with EF 6 and want to use Model First with Table per Hierarchy.  I've been searching for 2+ hours for a solution to no avail.

In the Model Designer, I *only* have TPT as a choice. It seems that TPH is in the "Entity Designer Database Generation Power Pack" for VS 2010 but I read that this doesn't work in 2012 so I assume it doesn't for 2013 as well. I saw that for Code First TPH is the default inheritance strategy so is the answer to convert a Code First project using TPH to Model First? Can Model First and TPH even be done? What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

I would always do it model first.

Here is a (simple) manual way to make TPH after you generate entities from database:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618292

Comment: Hey Saša-

Thx for your quick answer, you made the lightbulb go on.  I hadn't realized that a Db First strategy easily becomes a Model First strategy when you just deploy the model to another db.  So yes, that article did it for me, I worked through it last night.  One thing I don't get though is that for the fields specific to the derived entities need Nullable = false, why is that?  So it's a required field for the *derived* type but optional for the *base* type?  I assumed that this was being specified for the latter but it must be the opposite ...

Thx again,
-Pete

Comment: Atributes specific for a derived type in TPH are nullable in database, but don't have to be nullable when mapped to objects. For example, you can keep 'nullable=true' for enrollment date if it's not a required information.